# \sum does not work properly inside bmatrix

Tags: pdftex

I use the following code snippet to formulate a convolution operation:

```
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  * 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
    b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
    b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{32} \\
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sum_{\mathclap{m=1}}^{3} \sum_{\mathclap{n=1}}^{3}a_{n,m}b_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Why are the sum symbols squished together?

Comment: It's working exactly as you have told it to do...Ditch the `\mathclap`.  That could only possibly make some sense in `\displaystyle`, but your matrix is in `\textstyle`.

Comment: the `\mathclap` works normally outside of the matrix, the squishing only happens inside a matrix. I need the `\mathclap` because the matrix would be very wide (with a 3x3 matrix for example) @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: One alternative is to try `\sum\limits`, but even then, you will need to eliminate the `\mathclap`.  Perhaps you are looking for `\displaystyle` inside the matrix, to lead off the term.

Comment: `\sum` and `\mathclap` are working exactly as designed in your example, you are hiding the width of the subscript so it is over-printing the base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation is setting exactly the way you told it to.  Do not use `\mathclap` in `\textstyle`, since the limits are set to the right of the `\sum`.  If you want limits above/below the `\sum`, you can either add `\limits` after `\sum` or else specify `\displaystyle`.  While `\mathclap` can be useful sometimes in such cases, it would not help here, since you have two `\sum`s, adjacent to each other...subscripts will collide.

These are your choices.  None involve `\mathclap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sum_{m=1}^{3} \sum_{n=1}^{3}a_{n,m}b_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{3} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}a_{n,m}b_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \displaystyle\sum_{{m=1}}^{3}\sum_{{n=1}}^{3}a_{n,m}b_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\displaystyle` saved my day. Thank you very much